# How to output disk size in GB only with no rounding error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, bash, partitioning

Output disk size in GB only.  Giga Bytes only.
Not MB.  Not Mega Bytes.
Not TB.  Not Tera Bytes.

Tested thus far:

`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda`
1000204886016

`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda |bc -l |awk '{print $1/1000000000}'` 
1000.2

`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda |bc -l |awk '{print $1/1000000000}' |numfmt --field=1- --format=%.0f --invalid=ignore`
1001

But above `1001` output is a rounding error.
`1000` is ideal output, meaning `1000 GB` disk size.

Question1:
How to fix above rounding error?

Question2:
What is a more elegant way or shorter way versus 120 characters below:
`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda |bc -l |awk '{print $1/1000000000}' |numfmt --field=1- --format=%.0f --invalid=ignore`

.
.

using:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

--